# postgres partial index ignored when null column

Tags: postgresql, indexing

can't wrap it around my head - i have postgres table and want to disallow to have two processes with the same name when none of them is not deleted:

```sql
  create table process
  (
    pr_id           bigserial    not null,
    pr_name         varchar(255) not null,

    pr_deleted_date timestamptz  null,

    constraint process_pkey primary key (pr_id)
  );
  create unique index process_pr_name on process (pr_name) where (pr_deleted_date is not null);
```

and partial unique simple doesn't work

```sql
insert into process (pr_name) values ('x', 'draft');
insert into process (pr_name) values ('x', 'draft'); -- this is fine too
```

i dint find anything usefull in docs and chatgpt is no use either

Comment: Your index is set up to only enforce uniqueness for rows `where (pr_deleted_date is not null)` -- probably you want `WHERE pr_deleted_date IS NULL` instead, so uniqueness is only enforced for non-deleted rows?